# How to get a ThemingColor (like getThemingColor) for a object in Autodesk Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I understand that Autodesk Platform Services provides methods like clearThemingColor and setThemingColor, but I have been unable to locate documentation for a corresponding getThemingColor method. Despite searching the web, I have not found any solutions that fit my needs.

To provide more context, I am trying to determine whether a specific object ID has a ThemingColor associated with it. To achieve this, I have tried the following:

- Searching the Autodesk Platform Services documentation for
  information on how to retrieve a ThemingColor for a specific object
  ID.
- Consulting various web resources for similar examples, but none of them have provided a solution to my problem.

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to retrieve a ThemingColor for a specific object ID in Autodesk Platform Services. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/revisiting-viewers-theming-coloring-selective-cancelling-deferred-rendering-and-recursive) can help you. You'll find a method to get object themingColor and some useful details about this method.

Comment: If you want the theming color applied to the object, the blog post @AlexAR mentioned should be what you're looking for. Unfortunately, there is no viewer method called getThemingColor for that propose.